# Ag-grid synchronize data between two grids

Tags: javascript, angular, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is is possible to synchronize the data between two ag-grid tables?

**Basic example:**

I have a table that contains products with 3 columns: name, category and price. In the second table I will show the total price value for each category.
The first table is editable and when the price for a product has changed, the second table needs to be updated.

**Real scenario**

In my case, the data is more complex  but the idea is the same.

P.S I didn't provide an example because the idea is simple. I just need to know if this is possible.

Comment: if you have an `ag-grid cell editor` change the data of the second grid on cell value change and refresh.

Comment: @HDJEMAI, is it possible to get the current data of a grid?

Comment: You have to add some code to your question about what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

After updating the first grid you should update data for the second grid

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: your question only about if is it possible, when some value in the first grid is edited  - after that change we should redraw the second grid